# I have two datagridview, one on the staff calls, I want to make the other contain the number of staff did the call

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

The following images show my two datagrid views
[image: Datagridviews]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not very clear. What do you already have (e.g. Database tables)? What did you already try and where exactly do you have a problem? See also how to [ask]

Comment: I've edited the question to display the images which you linked, but the question remains extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you can use the following method

```
      public DataTable numOfCalls(DataTable table)
    {
        //Initialize Result Table
        DataTable numOfCallsTable = new DataTable();
        numOfCallsTable.Columns.Add("agentName", typeof(string));
        numOfCallsTable.Columns.Add("numOfCall", typeof(int));

        // Get the unique agents
        DataView view = new DataView(table);
        DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "agentName");

        // Check if there are agents
        if (distinctValues.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // Loop thru the agents
            for (int i = 0; i < distinctValues.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string agentName = distinctValues.Rows[i]["agentName"].ToString();
                // Get all the rows that this agent has
                DataRow[] agentRows = table.Select($"agentName='{agentName}'");
                // And then fill the second table
                DataRow newRow = numOfCallsTable.NewRow();
                newRow["agentName"] = agentName;
                newRow["numOfCall"] = agentRows.Length;
                numOfCallsTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }
        return numOfCallsTable;
    }
```

You can call this method every time you add or delete a line to the first table.

update for the button that you asked

```
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

            dataGridView2.DataSource = numOfCalls(dt);

        }
```

Comment: I want to execute on datagridview1 and datagridview2 through by button1 of the DGV1 contains evidence and DGV2 contains the number of what each employee has done

Comment: you can use DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource; to fill a table from the first datagridview and then datagridview2.DataSource = numOfCalls(dt)